# CSS styling when using a media query is not working as intended

Tags: css

This is the codepen:
    https://codepen.io/GummyGod/pen/XZqbKY
That's the query i wrote:

```
 @media screen and (max-width:500px){
.content{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
 }

.sidebar {
    order:-1;
 }

.resume {
    width:100%;
    order:;
 }
}
```

Basically,at the end of the css file i made a css media query in order to make it responsive at widths from 0 to 500px ,however, when the size is in that range of pixels that weird tag shows up and i can't seem to be able to style it

Comment: Your title should reflect the question. Don't title your questions like this in the future.

Comment: Done,re-phrased it

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It would really be to your advantage to read [ask] and [mcve]. The relevant content needs to be here, in the post itself, and not in an off-site location. The reason is simple: If it's in an off-site location, and that link isn't available (deleted, off-line, moved, etc.), then it's not available to reproduce the problem. This site is designed to be a collection of knowledge for future users, which means content needs to be preserved here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Remove `width` and `float:left` for sidebar,main classes. Adjust padding for space between sidebar and main class based on your need.

```
.sidebar, .main {
    display: table-cell;
}
```